# use epoll with netcore on centos7

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, epoll

i am a fresher for the linux programing related areas, i want to write a server which will keep long live connection with client site. the reuqirement descritbed this server should be hosted within a linux server.

would anyone please help to share some example or reference for me on how to begin with c# epoll coding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MonoDevelop, the IDE associated with Mono Project should be enough for C# development on Linux. Now I don't know any good profilers and other tools for C# development on Linux. But then again mind you, that C# is a language more native to windows. You are better developing C# apps for windows than for linux.

EDIT: When you download MonoDevelop from the Ubuntu Software Center, it will contain pretty much everything you need to get started right away (Compiler, Runtime Environment, IDE). If you would like more information, see the following links:

http://monodevelop.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29

http://www.mono-project.com/Development_Environments

Comment: Thanks, but i've found that netcore is supported on *nix systems, the mono is also a part of dotnet eco-system, is there any way i can use netcore(1.x, 2.0) instead?

Comment: Yes u can , here the link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/10/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-1/

Comment: Thanks again, i have checked the source code of netcore, it indeed invoked the epoll, but i the descrpition for the api saids "The System.Net.Sockets namespace provides a managed implementation of the Windows Sockets (Winsock) interface for developers who need to tightly control access to the network." i feel confused.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets(v=vs.110).aspx